# Actor is getting killed before processing the message

Tags: akka, akka-stream, dead-letter, alpakka

I am using akka streams. So i am having one actor with this functionality.

Both messages were getting processed in order sometimes . but due to async call (I THINK) , i am getting dead letter in this.

```java
actor.tell(message,ActorRef.noSender()); 
actor.tell(PoisonPill.getInstance(),ActorRef.noSender())
```

Can anyone help how to make sure to run this code in specific order?

Comment: They should arrive in order. Perhaps add some logging in the actor to see what's going on?

Comment: You don't show the Akka Streams part of your code. The two above tells should get processed in order, but it's conceivable something else is stopping the actor.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you are getting an exception which is killing the stream. Are you using a supervision strategy? If not, I would recommend following the documentation: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#supervision-strategies

If it is in some async call, it might be the future is throwing a `TimeoutException`.